# PHP Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array

Tags: php, error-handling, arguments, array-merge

Here is my code snippet..

```
$arr = [];
//$csv is your array
foreach($csv as $key => $value){
  if(!array_key_exists(@$value[24],$arr)){
    $arr[@$value[24]] = [];
  }
  $arr[@$value[24]] = array_merge($arr[@$value[24]],$value);  
}
//Ignore 1st line 
array_pop($arr);

//Array as order
foreach(array_slice($arr, 0, @$_GET["pages"]) as $order) : ?>

<!--HTML HERE-->

<?php {
} endforeach; ?>
```

and the specific line getting the error..

```
  $arr[@$value[24]] = array_merge($arr[@$value[24]],$value);
```

Can I stop this error with "if" "is_array" and if so how to I insert it in the code, or is there something else I'm doing wrong or should be looking at?

I have read over several similar questions and i'm just not understanding what I need to put where to fix this.

Comment: Without knowing what `$csv` contains and what you are trying to do, it's difficult to know how to solve the problem.  You can test using `is_array()`, which may get rid of the error, but also may stop it doing anything.

Comment: Something you should stop using as well is `@` all over the place.  If you are not sure if a  field is set, check using `isset()` and only continue if the value is there.  Alternatively use `??` to set some default value.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, the truth is I haven't a scooby what I'm doing and have amazed myself at how far i've got with this given my lack of understanding! if i want to try it with is_array() where do I put that in my code, please? and if that fails to do what I require (or stops doing anything)  I will anonymize an example of $csv (as it currently contains personal info) and add it to the OP

Comment: Can you share a basic glimpse of the contents of $csv. And let us know of the purpose of this code snippet, like the input, expected processing and the tentative output so that it can be verifiable. That would really help.